# Debug Flash with Firefox (FlashBuilder 4.7)?

Tags: flash, firefox, flash-builder

It's been awhile since I've had a Flash project, but lo and behold now I do!  I'm trying to get up and running with FlashBuilder 4.7 and FireFox.  However, whenever I go to debug a project, FireFox claims that no Flash Player is installed and FlashBuilder isn't able to make a connection to the debug player.

I seem to recall having this issue before, and thought it might have something to do with security issues with FireFox opening local files and executing JavaScript.

At any rate, I can't figure it out.  Does anybody know a solution to this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to put the same question to Mozilla, but found this in the process (annoying that it did not come up in a Google search).

> 1. In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and
>      press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful.
> 2. In the search box above the list, type or paste `plug*ht` and pause
>      while the list is filtered.
> 3. Double-click the `plugins.http_https_only` preference to switch the
>      value from `true` to `false`.

Original post:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1171493

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FB 4.6 instead of 4.7, but I think this should work.  Forgive me if some of the suggestions are of the "is the power cord plugged in?" type, I just want to make sure everything is covered.

1) Make sure you have a debug Flash Player installed - in Firefox, go to http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html to check your Flash Player version.

2) What browser is set up as your default (Windows -> Preferences, General -> Web Browser)?  Make sure you've got Firefox set up and selected.

3) Make sure your app was built as debuggable.  (I tend to debug apps built externally to FB - from inside FB this should be done already?)

4) I tend to debug my apps by having the app connect to the running debugger - i.e., in the Debug Configuration for the app, don't use the default path, and enter "about:blank" as the URL.  When the app starts under a debugging Flash Player, it tries to connect to the debugger.  If you get the "cannot locate the required debugger version" error, click "Yes" (try anyway).  Then start the app in Firefox.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Unfortunately, it's not working.  I think the problem is more basic than that.  If I try opening an HTML from my local hard drive that has a Flash embed, it just doesn't run claiming the plugin is not installed.  I've even tried opening a banner I built ages ago, and it just doesn't want to run in Firefox.  I suspect there must be some security setting that is preventing Flash from running correctly.